# Html video not playing

Tags: php, html

[image]When i am trying to play a video in my website i am getting black screen with frames but same video is playing in my xampp . But in my server video is not playing. This is my code

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="/post/SampleVideo_1280x720_2mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

In my server when i run domain.com/post/samplevideo.mp4 i am getting following screen

Comment: Check the path of the src.

Comment: Your video file is broken. Tried to download it and play, not working.

Comment: path is correct.

Comment: Try to convert the path to URL and try if it works.

Comment: how did you upload the file to your domain? FTP?

Comment: Use the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Network tab. Compare the HTTP responses for the video file in the working environment and the non-working environment. Probably you have the wrong content-type, possibly you have some broken compression going on which is sending the wrong content-length, possibly you corrupted the file in the process of uploading it to the server.

Comment: Try closing some tabs. o_0

Answer (score -1):

After trying to download your video I have found that video file is broken.

Your solution is:

1. Play video on your local disk, if it's working continue with point 2.
2. Upload it again to correct folder
3. Open your url and hit CTRL + S to download your file
4. Play the downloaded file again on local disk to see if it's working

If this is working problem is somewhere else, but it looks like your file which you have uploaded is broken.

Answer (score -1):

- check your post folder permission. (/post/SampleVideo_1280x720_2mb.mp4)
- then try to run video url directly.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of providing half path of Video try providing the whole path as

if your video path is : **http://www.fakeurl.com/assets/video/Sample.mp4**

then ,

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://www.fakeurl.com/assets/video/Sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```